# Specifying input format type when calling openssl_pkcs7_verify in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, pkcs#7

I have a crypto/php question, I was hoping someone could help me with.
My issue is that I have a signed PKCS7 block that I am trying to verify in PHP.
However, when I run the following PHP command:

```
openssl_pkcs7_verify($myfile, PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_NOVERIFY, $signers_file);
```

I get the following error:

```
PKCS7 routines:SMIME_read_PKCS7:no content type
```

If I do it using ruby like so:

```
p7container = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(file_contents);
mystore = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
p7container.verify(nil, store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
```

It works.

Also, if I run it through the OpenSSL commandline:

```
openssl smime -verify -inform der -in my_data_file -noverify
```

It also works. However, if I run the following:

```
openssl smime -verify -in my_data_file -noverify
```

Which is the same command, but without specifying the inform parameter, it fails with the same error message specified before, regarding the "no content type", which makes it seem I need to specify the input file format. Any ideas how I can do that through PHP?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around that problem by calling openssl directly from PHP (using the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function). Be sure to add 2>&1 to the command to redirect stderr to stdout as the message "Verification successful" is sent to stderr.

```
function verify($signedData, &$data = null) {
    @mkdir("tmp");
    $random = randomString(32);
    $signedFile = "tmp/" . $random . ".pem";
    $file = "tmp/" . $random . ".dat";
    file_put_contents($signedFile, $signedData);
    $output = exec("openssl smime  -verify -in $signedFile -inform DER -noverify -out $file 2>&1");
    if ($output == "Verification successful") {
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    @unlink($signedFile);
    @unlink($file);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi @goldmine,
Thanks for your response. That is actually what we ended up doing as well, but we were wondering if there was a way to set the -inform option in the openssl_pkcs7_verify call directly, especially since there might be more pkcs7 calls we want to make, and wouldn't necessarily want to call the commandline tool for each call.

Comment: @Hawkeye001, the only thing closest to using the openssl_pkcs7_verify function would be to base64 encode the file before using it in the function (more details in this link http://www.rootmanager.com/iphone-ota-configuration/iphone-ota-setup-with-signed-mobileconfig.html, see section "Sign the .mobileconfig" file that talks about using php to signing .mobileconfig: inverting that should give what we want). However, I'll probably stick to using exec.